# ASP.Net Web api url is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am new in **web api**.
i am sure i am doing something wrong for which my action is not getting called.

### this is my action

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country)
{
    return repository.GetAll().Where(
        c => string.Equals(c.Country, country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

when i am calling this action this way `http://localhost:38762/api/customer/GetCustomersByCountry/Germany`

the error is thrown, and error message is

> `{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:38762/api/customer/GetCustomersByCountry/Germany'.","MessageDetail":"No
>   action was found on the controller 'Customer' that matches the
>   request."}`

tell me where i made the mistake ? thanks

### Web config routes are

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "WithActionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{customerID}"
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

### EDIT : Full code added

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    static readonly ICustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(string customerID)
    {
        Customer customer = repository.Get(customerID);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return customer;
    }

    //[ActionName("GetCustomersByCountry")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country)
    {
        return repository.GetAll().Where(
            c => string.Equals(c.Country, country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        customer = repository.Add(customer);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Customer>(HttpStatusCode.Created, customer);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { customerID = customer.CustomerID });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }

    public void PutProduct(string customerID, Customer customer)
    {
        customer.CustomerID = customerID;
        if (!repository.Update(customer))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }

    public void DeleteProduct(string customerID)
    {
        Customer customer = repository.Get(customerID);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        repository.Remove(customerID);
    }
}
```

just tell me when controller will have multiple get whose parameter name is different then how could i handle the situation.

thanks

Comment: share your webapiroute.config, without that its hard to tell

Comment: use follwoing url http://localhost:38762/api/customer/GetCustomersByCountry?country="Germany"

Comment: web api route added :)

Comment: the code taken from http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/rest-based-crud-operations-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx  this is not design by me

Comment: no body answer properly what is wrong or how to rectify but efficiently give negative marks

Comment: @MonojitSarkar before expecting everyone to just tell you what is wrong you should show some effort in researching the answer. A simple search can go a long way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given CustomerController like

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country) {
        return repository.GetAll().Where(
            c => string.Equals(c.Country, country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

}
```

a convention-based route can look like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CustomerApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/customer/{action}/{countryId}",
    default: new { controller = "Customer"}
);
```

which will map `http://localhost:38762/api/customer/GetCustomersByCountry/Germany`

The problem with your route is that your parameter name in the route template does not match.

Another option could be to use attribute routing

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
[RoutePrefix("api/customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController {
    //GET api/customer/country/germany
    [HttpGet, Route("country/{country}")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country) {
        return repository.GetAll().Where(
            c => string.Equals(c.Country, country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }    
}
```

with this configuration

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Other Web API configuration not shown.
    }
}
```

Comment: my situation is i have multiple get action and u shown with your code just one. say one get action argument name is id, where other has country so tell me how to handle this situation. just adding my full code and you see and tell me how to handle it nicely with multiple get whose parameter name is different.

Comment: I just showed one as an example based on your question. You can have multiple get actions once they don't conflict with each other

Comment: if possible post a link or example where multiple get action will be there where each action will have one or more argument whose name will be different. looking for further help. thanks

Comment: please see my full code with routing code because there is many Get action and now tell me what i need to change in routine code or any area in code as a result i should be able to call my all get action by name over url `
http://localhost:38762/api/customer/GetAllCustomers
http://localhost:38762/api/customer/GetCustomer/1
http://localhost:38762/api/customer/GetCustomersByCountry/Germany`

Answer (score 1):

Remove "Get" from the action in the url. Just keep CustomersByCountry instead of GetCustomersByCountry. So the url should be http://localhost:38762/api/customer/CustomersByCountry/Germany.

Comment: just remove get from url or do i need to change action name in controller where i need to remove get ?

Comment: please tell me why u r saying to remove get from url.........need clarification. help me to know the reason. thanks

Comment: sorry i gave u the vote without check but i remove get from url still no luck

Comment: decorate you action with [HttpGet] attribute.

Comment: my action name like GetCustomersByCountry. i heard that when action name start with Get then we should not use  HttpGet verb. so tell me why u said to use HttpGet verb ? i need clarification for your answer.